# How is C syntax different on x64 processors

Tags: c, pointers, memory, gnu

I'm reading a book about C, and GNU but it references code on a 32 bit processor. I've already figured out that EIP is actually RIP on 64 bit, but it keeps giving me woods when I deal with pointers... Are there done some more differences that I'm not aware of??? Thanks - pointer code -

```
int j = 10;
int *pointr;
pointr = j;

printf("in j has an adress of %p", pointr);
```

Comment: C is a source language, not an instruction set architecture. Its syntax is independent of any processor.

Comment: This question, should perhaps be rewritten to either be "What am I doing wrong with pointers?" Or "How is C syntax different on x64 processors?"  removing all references to the other, with what is decided on.

Comment: Man, the number of answers that all appear at once when anyone asked a basic programming question

Comment: No one mentioned it yet; you can be notified of this type of type mismatch problem if you enable warnings. For gcc try `-Wall -Wextra` for maximum diagnostics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be

```
pointr = &j;
```

With `pointr = j;` you are assigning value of `j` i.e `10` to the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of C is the same on all processors.

What is different are the sizes of the different native types.  There are rules for what is permitted, but there is also an awful lot of scope for inventiveness.  In particular, pointers are 8 bytes long on a 64-bit machine, rather than 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine. Most 32-bit compilers treat both `int` and `long` as 32-bit types; most 64-bit compilers treat `long` as a 64-bit type, the notable exception being Windows 64 where `long` remains a 32-bit type.

Note that your code should be:

```
int j = 10;
int *pointr = &j;
printf("int j has an address of %p\n", pointr);
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't.

Except some sizes of variables (esp pointers) might be different. 
This should almost never matter but if it does,
you should be using `sizeof` to get sizes if they ever matter.

However your code should probably be taking the address of `j`
Whether in 64bit or 32 bit

```
int j = 10; int *pointr;
pointr = &j;
printf("in j has an adress of %p", pointr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The one major thing that changes when not using inline assembly is the pointer size. If your program doesn't explicity depend on the pointer size, you should usually be fine.

See http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0065/ for a detailed list of problems with 64-bit C/C++ code.

In your code, you should use:

```
pointr = &j;
```